# Is there a way to extract arbitrary data from a Swift decoder?

Tags: swift, decoding

Here's the deal : I'm making a level editor for a game, and I'd like to try to support modded content. Is there some way, when initialising from a `Decoder`, that I could ask it to "Give me the rest of the data" ?

Something like :

```
var json = "{\"name\" : \"test\", \"modData\" : 35}"

struct Something : Codable {
    var name : String
    var additional : [String : any Codable] // Possibly the wrong type

    private enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
        case name, additional
    }

    init(from decoder : Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        name = container.decode(String.self, forKey: .name)
        additional = //Is there any way to get modded data out here ?
    }
}
```

The idea being that `modData` is something I couldn't possibly have known about when implementing the thing, but I still retain *some* level of compatibility with like showing it in the inspector and allowing you to change its value.

I'm almost certain this is impossible, but maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: @Sweeper I have edited the question to make it a `[String : any Codable]` dictionary. Honestly though, that's just a guess. But I'd like it to be a dict so I can `ForEach` on the keys in the interface.

Comment: `[String: any Codable]` won't work, because Swift doesn't know how to decode an `any Codable`. It needs a concrete type. Since this is for supporting mods, how about letting mod creators implement their own `init(from: Decoder)`?

Comment: @Sweeper that's probably what I'll end up doing. Either that or foregoing the use of a `Decoder` and initialising from the intermediary format my current one uses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the struct generic, the compiler creates `CodingKeys` and the `init` method on your behalf.

```
struct Something<T: Decodable> : Decodable {
    var name : String
    var additional : T
}
```

But at the moment you are going to use it you must specify the static type of `T`. It can be anything, a single value or a collection type which conforms to `Decodable`.

Comment: One caveat to this is the additional data would have to be literally called "additional" in the json, and one of the issues is I won't know the names of that data until I decode it.

Comment: Then `JSONDecoder` is the wrong API. It you don't know the keys use `JSONSerialization`

Comment: Well it's only json for the example, the actual file is a custom format. Fortunately I have basically already made a `JSONSerialization` equivalent that sits between the `Decoder` and the file, so I guess I'm just going to go off of that.

Comment: I have accepted your answer as the correct one, the most helpful part is in a comment so maybe you could add it to the body just in case someone asks themselves this in the future ?

Comment: I don't think I'm going to be able to support modded stuff like this. I'm going to use my `JSONSerialization` equivalent to make a "Compatibility Mode" at a later date, and ask the user to choose a mode if I detect the save file to be modded.